# How can i install Apps from other sources?

Tags: release-loki, applications, appcenter

I just install Loki and i love it! It is a fast, lightweight and beautiful OS!!

My problem has come when I'm trying to install my favourite apps, like Uberwriter and Google Chrome.

I knew about the app center, but i hope we can edit the software source or add repositorys. This is not the case... and the app center only show software that is already instaled on my system.

Thank you for the support!

Eduardo

---

Thanks you all.

I know i can install Chromium but i want install Chrome. In the other hand, I'm trying Epiphany and i love it.

I have install the software that was linked below and everithing works fine. Sadly, the ppa of uberwriter is not waorking.

So, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common - for adding repository.

sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk - GUI

sudo apt-get install gdebi - for *.deb

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Chrome through the *App Center* you can search for "**Chromium**". Chromium is the free (open) version of Chrome and supports the same things.