# Software Sources in Juno

Tags: software-sources

I am trying to reach the Software Sources. 
Where has this functionality has been moved to in Juno?
Or is it completely removed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, removed, but can be installed - as already mentioned [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/7869/170).

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk
```

Let's hope the rest will work great.

It's called *Software and Updates* and can be found as such by the launcher.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a little confusing how some pretty common features get removed by default. Thankfully, there's an easy fix!